# AIX - collect network traffic with process ID-s

Tags: aix, tcpdump

I am into analyzing network communication directions of an appserver machine. I collected a lot of TCP SYN packages, so I can list network communication directions inward and outward.

The inward communications are clean, as I can tell which appserver processes are related to a certain LISTEN port.

My problem is to tell which process is initiating a communication to a particular direction.

For example in my tcpdump output I see outbound packages to  123.123.110.120:10122.

```
07:52:47.308694 IP 10.128.46.13.49743 > 123.123.110.120.10122: S 246322753:246322753(0) win 14600 <mss 1460,sackOK,timestamp 3109396548 0,nop,wscale 7>
```

Is there a way to collect process ID-s along with tcpdump outs?

Comment: `lsof` can do that, e.g. `/usr/local/bin/lsof -nP -i @10.128.46.13:49743 -i @10.128.46.13:otherport ...` but it does require some scripting work.

Comment: Well, thanks. The problem is that most network traffic takes place so quickly that I can not   capture them, or at least I can not be sure to capture ALL of them.

Comment: You could start with lsof: run it every second and collect the output for some time. `while sleep 1; do lsof -nP -i watchthisIP:watchthisPort >>watch.log; done`